# PHP setcookie with small timeout value not working?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

`setcookie('cdate', date('Ymd'), time() + 120);`

`setcookie('cdate', date('Ymd'), time() + 82500);`

I was trying to set a cookie with 2 minutes expired time. Strangely, no cookie is set with no. 1 but no. 2 it is working. I view the cookie in chrome and firefox. Any idea?

Btw, i am running php + IIS in my windows 7 locally.

Comment: Try this `time() + (60 * 2)`

Comment: Is there a difference? Anyway the result is same, not working.

Comment: Both of your examples are working for me. Tested in chrome and firefox and XAMPP, win7. So my guess is that the IIS server is causing the problem. `

Comment: You are right but i tried with other's pc with exact same setup and it's working. Strange, can't figure out what caused this in my pc...

Comment: Are the clocks in sync? If both systems don't have the same internal time and differ by, let's say, *2 minutes* or more, you may get this result...

Comment: The browser, php, IIS all runs in my local pc sharing the same clock.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your server time (it must be same with computer time): `var_dump(date('H:i:s'))`. If it not the same with your computer time, you can change **timezone** on your server.

Comment: The browser, php, IIS all runs in my local pc and has same timezone setting.